# What does Yuuma want to do on Earth?

Tags: world-trigger

I want to know what does Yuuma want to do on Earth. Wherever I see it, it's not full episodes so I couldn't see if he knew he was dying, or there are other reasons he came to Japan?

Answer (score 3):

Yuma is a Neighbour form another world.
He comes to Earth (also named otherwise in the multiverse used in World Trigger) searching for a friend of his father.

> as his father gives up his life to save Yuma, granting him a constant trion body and producing a black trigger at the same time, Yuma remembers his father speaking very fondly of a "friend" on Earth, which he helped to turn away other neighbours...

Comment: FYI, you can hide spoilers but putting ">!" before the appropriate section.

Answer (score 1):

**Yuma comes to Japan not only because his late father told him so**

> [image: Yuma reason for going to Japan 1]

**But also for his personal reason:**

> *He wants to resurrect his father*
>
>
>  [image: Yuma reason for going to Japan 2]

Sources: Volume 3 Chapter 18 & Chapter 20